# Can XmlSerializer(Type) throw randomly?

Tags: c#, .net

We have a confusing case, where code that runs normally hundreds of times suddenly stopped working. It is an application that usually runs for weeks.

The question is, do `XmlSerializer(Type)` have some cache somewhere, which can be corrupted?

The background:

It happened at startup, at one occasion, that we got a lot of exceptions. After a restart when the problem was detected (a few days later), it ran normally again.

We have tracked down the problem to this code:

```
internal static class StateManager
{
    private static XmlSerializer queueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<QueueItem>));

    private static readonly string queuePath = Path.Combine(SubSystem.PersistentDirectory, "Queue.xml");

    internal static void SaveQueue(List<QueueItem> upcomingTasks)
    {
        XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(queuePath, xmlSettings);
        queueSerializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, upcomingTasks);
        xmlWriter.Close();
    }

    internal static List<QueueItem> GetQueue()
    {
        var queue = new List<QueueItem>();

        try
        {
            var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmlDoc.Load(queuePath);
            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xmlDoc.OuterXml)))
            {
                queue = queueSerializer.Deserialize(reader) as List<QueueItem>;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            AppTrace.Write(TraceLevel.Error, string.Format("Failed to load State Queue: {0}", e.Message));
        }

        return queue;
    }
}
```

and the error we get is:

```
Failed to load State Queue: The type initializer for 'StateManager' threw an exception.
```

As we understand it, this leaves two possibilities for the culprit:

```
private static XmlSerializer queueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<QueueItem>));
```

or

```
    private static readonly string queuePath = Path.Combine(SubSystem.PersistentDirectory, "Queue.xml");
```

We have checked `SubSystem.PersistentDirectory` carefully, and believe it to be innocent.

Since this happened in the field at a client's machine, and we cannot reproduce it, checking the inner exception is not possible.

Comment: What's `SubSystem.PersistentDirectory` ?

Comment: Look at the exception in more detail - it should include an inner exception giving the exact cause.

Comment: @Jon Skeet This is unfortunately a post mortem analysis of a rare event, we can't look at it in a debugger.

Comment: I didn't suggest using a debugger. You should have the full stack trace in your log, which should include the inner exception. If you don't have the full stack trace in the log, that's the *first* thing to fix.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Very true!

Answer (score 1):

You should catch that ! I see there is no static ctor there, you might attempt something like this, deferring initialization so you're able to know more:

```
internal static class StateManager
{
    private static XmlSerializer queueSerializer;
    private static readonly string queuePath;

    internal static StateManager(){
        try
        {
            queueSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<QueueItem>));
            queuePath = Path.Combine(SubSystem.PersistentDirectory, "Queue.xml");
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Log, log, log!
            throw; // Essential: you MUST rethrow!
        }
    }
}
```

As far as the actual offending line, there is no way to tell for sure without a trace: all you know is that your type could not be initialized, with no indications about the *why*.
The most likely causes, as far as I can guess, are:

- Something is broken in the data you feed to the `XmlSerializer` (not the `XmlSerializer` itself: I *highly* doubt that anything coming from the `System` namespace is prone to blowing up at random)
- Your `SubSystem.PersistentDirectory` contains broken data
- (Unlikely, but you never know...) Something *else* is broken and the exception is not actually related to the offending code, which might reside elsewhere

Comment: That we definitely should do, and the answer is very appreciated! But it does not answer the question as it is written, if it _can_ be the XmlSerializer.

Comment: I amended the answer with some considerations about the issue... in short: I tend to assume that "if it comes from `System` namespace, it works as expected".